# ARM64 branch out of range

Tags: ios, xcode, arm64

All I get the following compile errors when compiling to the device(Iphone 5s):

final section layout:

```
    __TEXT/__text addr=0x1000044B4, size=0x0AC5D808, fileOffset=0x000044B4, type=1

...


ld: b(l) ARM64 branch out of range (180743200 max is +/-128MB): from __ZN10ClassNameEv (0x100004560) to __Unwind_Resume@0x00000000 (0x10AC6351C) 
in '__ZN10ClassNameC2Ev' from  /Users/Name/Desktop/Projectpath/Debug-iphoneos/Project.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ClassName.o for  architecture arm64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

`"Valid Architectures"` is `"armv7 armv7s arm64"`.

`"Build Active Architecture Only"` is `NO`.

**Question :** Do you have any idea what I can do about this?

Comment: Did you try to clean & rebuild the project ? Also remove the App from device

Comment: I tried. But still get errors.

Comment: I also setted "Build Active Architecture Only" is YES, and compiled to the device(Iphone 4),it's OK. But compiled to the device(Iphone 5s) ,it's still gave me errors.

Comment: In Nintendo Entertainment System programming, branches have a range of 128 bytes, and trying to branch farther causes the assembler to throw a "branch out of range" error.  I'm guessing you are experiencing  a compiler/linker bug that is trying to generate a branch farther than the iPhone's maximum range.

Comment: My project have more than 800 files, I delete many files , at last, my project have less than 60 files, it works!  So, the problem is that my project add too many files ? Do you have any idea what I can do about this?

Comment: Now, my project Compile Sources is 640 items , it works. I think, the  error "ARM64 branch out of range"  showed, maybe my project added too many files . Am I right ?

Comment: @JTZS That sounds reasonable.  The error said the iPhone's maximum range was 128 MB (of machine code).  Removing files made the binary size less than the max branch range.  It still looks like a compiler/linker bug.

Comment: I'll test this theory later by writing a program to generate a ton of code and seeing if I get that error.  If I can reproduce it,  I'll file a bug report.

Comment: @NobodyNada :Thank you ,very much!

Comment: @JTZS I'm sorry I haven't done the test yet.  I meant to do it a few days ago, but I was busy and didn't get around to it.  I'll see if I can do it tomorrow or Thursday (Pacific Time Zone).

Comment: @NobodyNada : It doesn't matter, still thank you!